# How many aircraft could this submarine aircraft carrier carry on its flight deck?

Tags: technology, warfare, ships, mathematics, aircraft

I have a humongous submarine aircraft carrier (dubbed a *Kharybdis*-class submarine) shaped like a triangular arrowhead. This submarine can launch a wide variety of aircraft from its flight deck such as fighter jets (e.g, the Lockheed Martin F-35B/C Lightning II, Sukhoi Su-33 and Shenyang J-15), military cargo aircraft (e.g CH-53E Super Stallion, Mil Mi-26 and Airbus A400M Atlas) and various multi-mission aircraft. When the vessel is submerged, all aircraft are stored 40 feet below deck via watertight doors and securely held in place by a series of complex locking mechanisms.

Here are the typical measures of a *Kharybdis*-class submarine:

- **Length:** 665.7 meters | 2,184.0551 feet
- **Beam:** 81.68 meters | 267.979 feet
- **Flight Deck Width:** 153.6 meters | 503.937 feet
- **Displacement:** 711,339 metric tons

This pretty much what a *Kharybdis*-class submarine's body plan.

[image]
*Closest thing I could find.*

Now, here's the multi-billion dollar question: **how many aircraft could this submarine's flight deck carry?**

Comment: What stops you from multiplying?  Also, why are you carrying your aircraft on the flight deck?

Comment: Isn't this an exercise in counting? Compute the area of the storage deck, compute the area of an aircraft, divide the second into the first.

Comment: Are we talking about carrier aircraft with folding wings or land aircraft? The A400M is *huge*. And to you want to spot the maximum number of aircraft to launch a strike or do you need free area for landing?

Comment: "wide variety of aircraft" makes it too broad in my eyes. Pick one or two, see what runway and lift they need, and design taxi lanes and parking spots around that. That's all to it. But we can't do it for every aircraft and every combination of aitcrafts for you.

Comment: I'm curious how much space would be required to power the submarine side of things? Wouldn't it get complicated if you have all this room and air for planes to be stored in vs the said displacement of that air?

Comment: Please consider the difference between: "How much stuff would fit in there" and "What is a reasonable number". There is no need to carry aircrafts that you don't use. You have to maintain that stuff. You have to give the crew a chance to fill out physical space (unless they don't require pilots or human mechanics and so on). You have to consider the logistic nightmare. As of right now, it seems as you have given this little thought and research of your own

Comment: This really isn't an answer but it was way to long to comment in and it might help you Also worthy of note that the variety of aircraft the expected mission duration and a variety of other things makes a big difference here **Design** An arrowhead is a terrible design for a submarine... theres are 2 main reasons why Submarines are long tubes: 1. Better able to withstand extreme pressure 2. Less Drag The Arrowhead design means lots of drag and an extremely difficult job of engineering it to withstand extreme pressures, (not impossible just a lot more work) and when its surfaces its even easier

Comment: I don't have an answer, but have you ever thought about making the aircrafts amphibious or able to dive underwater (maybe even start from there)? It would mostly eliminate the need for a flight deck (except for maintenance) and you could think about just having the planes attached to the side of the submarine where they can be stored and refueled.

Comment: Terrible idea as for a plane to be launched or recovered (land) the sub has to surface, which adds a lot of time to the operation.  It appears to gain nothing being underwater and to loose the ability to rapidly launch aircraft - it's primary weapon system.  Even the Pentagon might spot this was a bad idea, well, maybe they would.